# Django: How to tell if an object has been updated after .save()

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django 1.5, I'm using the following code to store some data into my models:

```
new_object, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(
    pk = object.id,
    default = object_dict
)

if created:
   # ... code that creates a log  ... 
else:
    newobject.save()
    # ... code that creates a log IF the record has been updated
```

As the save() method returns None, is there a way to know if the saved actually been updated without comparing the two states of the objects (before and after saving)?

Comment: What do you mean by "has been updated"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_or_create` method would not do an update to an existing database entry, thus calling `newobject.save()` would have no effect on the already created instance, if you did not manually set/change some of the instance properties. Also your `get_or_create` syntax is wrong, take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create). Note, it should be defaults instead of default.

```
new_object, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(
    pk=object.id,
    defaults=object_dict
)
```

Answer (score 0):

get_or_create does not update, defaults is used for params that you do not want in the initial get query.

According to django docs:

```
defaults = kwargs.pop('defaults', {})
params = dict([(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items() if '__' not in k])
params.update(defaults)
obj = self.model(**params)
obj.save()
```